# Can't find my module

Tags: python, celery

I am having trouble in understanding the python paths concept. My program is not finding my classes when I launch the program. What should I do?

I launch my program with this script [1], and I do it like this [2]. The python files and subdirectories are in [3]. I have set the PYTHONPATH in [4], although I don't know if I should do it.

[1] Script to launch the program

```
#!/bin/bash
set -xv

export C_FORCE_ROOT="true"
HOST_NAME=`hostname`

MEDUSA_HOME=$HOME/Programs/medusa-2.0

echo "------------------------"
echo "Initialize celery at $HOST_NAME"
echo "------------------------"
CELERY_RDB_HOST=192.168.10.113
CELERY_RDB_PORT=6913
celery worker -n ${HOST_NAME} -E --loglevel=DEBUG --concurrency=5 -f ./logs/celerydebug.log --config=celeryconfig -Q ${HOST_NAME}
```

[2] How I launch the program

```
~/Programs/medusa-2.0$ ./bin/celery-debug.sh
```

[3] python files location

```
~/Programs/medusa-2.0/medusa
```

[4] Python path

```
export MEDUSA_HOME=$HOME/Programs/medusa
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:$MEDUSA_HOME/medusa:$MEDUSA_HOME/tests
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. If you want celery to load your tasks, you have to pass the `-A` option: `celery -A medusa worker...`.

Comment: I am saying that my python files can't be found when I launch celery. I have updated PYTHONPATH to `export MEDUSA_HOME=$HOME/Programs/medusa-2.0` and now it seems to work.

Comment: One time you use `$HOME/Programs/medusa-2.0` and the other `$HOME/Programs/medusa` are those two different directories or is it simply a mistake while pasting here?

Comment: It is a mistake in the config files. I have corrected and it seems that it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated PYTHONPATH to export MEDUSA_HOME=$HOME/Programs/medusa-2.0 and now it seems to work.